# ms access encoding problem ( connecting with jsp)

Tags: java, ms-access, encoding

After searching for hours i could not find the solution, expecting help as,

- I am connecting ms access database file (.mdb) from jsp using sun's jdbc driver and tomcat.
- jsp page's charset is set to "iso-8859-1" (i have tried setting it utf-8 with no luck).
- now storing user input (thai string- ทฟืรห้ททฟืรห้ท) into .mdb file , but when i look into database it converts to like `&#3607;&#3615;&#3639;&#3619;&#3627;&#3657;&#3607;&`, how can i store exact thai string into access database , please help.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is completely separate the JSP side from the Access side.

There may well be problems on *both* sides - but trying to diagnose them at the same time is going to be hopeless.

- Write a *console* application to read and write from the database. Don't just try printing the strings to the console: write out the Unicode character values as integers, and look them up on [the Unicode charts pages](http://unicode.org/charts).
- Give your JSP a different data source: one with hard-coded data to read, and logging (again, of Unicode code point values as integers) when writing. That way you can tell whether you can display data appropriately and what happens when the user enters data.

See [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/DebuggingUnicode.aspx) for a little more detail - it's C#-based, but the *principles* apply to Java and JSP.

Comment: hi jon, same application is working fine before suddenly i am facing this problem , i have tried to debug the jsp side and the string is correct but once its inserted in mdb its converted to html tags , do u think is a problem of ms-access storing of unicode?

Comment: @manish: I can't easily tell, but I know how I'd find out: I'd write a console application, exactly as I mentioned in the first bullet point.

Answer (score 0):

may be you are facing this problem cause of Localization and Globalization concept, try to add or activate that particular language in your browser.

Regards,
Vishal

Comment: hi vishal, this is used to work before but suddenly i started to face this problem , could you explain more how i set the localization or globalization ?